# Building a SPA from ASP.NET MVC Partial Views - Is it a good idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've spent quite a bit of time with React and Redux and enjoyed it, but at times it has felt like overkill for line of business apps with lots of CRUD, but not huge amounts of state held in the browser.

I got to wondering whether I could create a SPA in ASP.NET MVC using a single container element that I then swapped different partial views in and out of as the user navigated, thus giving me the nice behaviour of the whole page not reloading and also allowing me to use all of the helpful scaffolding, tooling and code-first database generation in Visual Studio, and also not to have to write all my validation logic in both JS and C# (as I would if using a SPA connected to a Web API backend).  A bit of initial experimentation certainly seems to suggest this is viable.

Obviously I'm not the first person to have this idea, Dino Esposito describes it in two articles on the Visual Studio Magazine site ([Simplifying Single-Page Applications with ASP.NET MVC Partial Views](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/07/01/simplifying-single-page-applications.aspx) and [Integrating Updates, Deletes and Inserts with TypeScript and ASP.NET MVC](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/08/01/integrating-updates-deletes-and-inserts.aspx)) and follows it up in [Revisiting Partial View Rendering in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp-net-mvc/).  John Fazzaro also explains one approach to routing [here](http://blog.apterainc.com/bid/313071/Turn-your-ASP-NET-MVC-app-into-a-Single-Page-Application-with-one-classy-Sammy-js-route).

Edit:
I'm going to focus this question to stop it being too broad. In my case I'm not so worried about network traffic as these line of business apps are bespoke in-house systems with relatively few users. In these cases dev time is more expensive than any possible infrastructure costs that might arise.

So, some specific questions:

1. Are there any obvious red-flags to this approach that make it a
   really bad idea?
2. Has anyone done this in production, and if so, how has it been to
   maintain? Did you suffer as the app grew bigger?
3. If we utilise the VS tooling, will this approach be faster to
   develop than writing a Web API back end and a Redux/React client?
4. Will we create memory leaks by repeatedly swapping partial views in
   and out?

Answer (score 1):

The main 'problem' with this approach is you are sending potentially large HTML responses, instead of pure JSON/XML/Other data. This sort-of defies the point as you still have large amount of network traffic, slowing things down and need a different partial view for each different representation of data...

It isn't a bad idea, it's just the main advantage of frameworks is that you can define 1 backend API (sending small JSON for example), then render different HTML as you want on multiple pages. This means less things to test, and less network traffic (also less server load).

A good middle ground approach is to use MVC or WebAPI to provide a JSON API, then use a smaller framework like backbone or knockout to render this into html templates.

Comment: These are all really good points and absolutely why I favour a proper SPA framework for writing larger B2C cloud apps, but for our line of business apps network traffic and server load are not really major concerns. For those apps development costs are a lot higher than the server hosting and so leveraging all of that clever scaffolding tooling has real benefits.  The problem with backbone/knockout etc. (I think) is that I now have to reproduce the validation logic client side, and write client side versions of all the objects in a different language to the server side originals?